# Boost regex ignoring "shortest match"

Tags: regex, boost

Here is a verbatim copy of a Python3 session:

```
~/Documents $ python3
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> text = 'This (is) a (test)'
>>> print(text)
This (is) a (test)
>>> re.findall('h', text)
['h']
>>> re.findall('\(.+?\)', text)
['(is)', '(test)']
>>> re.findall('\(.+?\)$', text)
['(is) a (test)']
>>>
```

I expected the final `findall` to return *only* `(test)`, as it's the shortest possible match for `\(.+?\)` *at the end of the string*. Instead, it returns `(is) a (test)`. It does the same for longer test strings:

```
>>> text = 'This (is) (possibly) a (test)'
>>> re.findall('\(.+?\)', text)
['(is)', '(possibly)', '(test)']
>>> re.findall('\(.+?\)$', text)
['(is) (possibly) a (test)']
```

For what reason does it match from the **first** occurrence of `(` on?

Please note that I am *not* looking for an alternative regex. This question is about the specific behavior, as it seems to be wrong.

---

I used Python only to verify; this is prompted by [this question](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2264423) in Adobe's InDesign forum, and InDesign also uses Boost:

> Adobe Indesign offers best of breed page design: Indesign and it's asociated SDK depend upon Boost Boost.Regex, Boost.Functional and others.
>   (http://www.boost.org/users/uses_shrink.html (*sic* the typos))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For what reason does it match from the first occurrence of ( on?

Because the parser state machine starts at the left. This is how it works. If there is a match starting from the first character, why should it be rejected?

That should give you a clue. You probably want to require that no parentheses  occur in the middle: `[^(]` instead of `.`

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> text = 'This (is) (possibly) a (test)'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\(.+?\)$', text)
['(is) (possibly) a (test)']
>>> re.findall('\([^(]+?\)$', text)
['(test)']
>>>
```

Comment: The rule "If there is a match starting from the first character, why should it be rejected ..", using a plain `\(.+\)`, should match the first `(is)` only. Of course there are more rules that this one – the Greedy Rule is "continue searching for the longest match". So, fully equivalent, one may expect a 'shortest match' to match the *shortest* possible string.

Comment: It IS the shortest possible match! All other shorter matches get rejected by your own requirement that it MUST end at the end of the string (`$`). (I thought I didn't need to point that out, as it is literally the only difference with the example you show just before). So it gives the first possible match, and the result is the shortest one that satisfies the criteria.

Comment: ... Are we talking about the same test results? Surely you cannot disagree that the string `(test)$` is way shorter than the current `'(is) a (test)$` – the `$` included for clarity. "Because the parser state machine starts at the left" would at `This` – but it's smart enough to skip *that*. And checking further than the absolutely required minimum is not a problem either (as indicated by the default Greedy checking rule).

Comment: It's NOT smart enough to skip "This". It skips that because your pattern starts with a mandatory `(`. So, it's already past `This ` before it starts to match, and it doesn't stop until it reaches the `$` (end of input), because that's also in your pattern.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it – the clue is in ".. it gives the first possible match, and the result is the shortest one that satisfies the criteria". A regex is evaluated left-to-right, and while it matches the `.+` it uses a 'lookahead' to check for the end criterium – which would be `\)$` here, not just `\)`. And it is considered the shortest possible match *because it literally is the only match* (it equals the match of its greedy version).

Comment: Spot on! Cheers